# Check invocation of class methods using Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

Using google test, I would like to check that some of class methods are invoked if I call another class method.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class Foo {

    void DoWorkPrivate(int i) {}

public:

    void DoWork(int i) {}

    void Run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            DoWork(i);
            DoWorkPrivate(i);
        }
    }
};

TEST(FooTest, Run) {
    Foo foo;    
    foo.Run(); // Need to check that DoWork() and DoWorkPrivate() are invoked
}
```

**QUESTION:**

How to check that `DoWork()` and `DoWorkPrivate()` are invoked 5 times with certain parameters (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way in this case is to create a Mock-Object. There are lot of literature and articles about mocking and the different types of Mocks. So I will not go to deep in detail here. e.g. [fowler about mocking](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

But in general you can subclass the class (or normally the interface of the class), you expect the method call.

That means for your example:

```
class FooMock : public Foo {
  public:
  bool isDoWorkPrivateCalled() {
    return isDoWorkPrivatecall;
  }

  private:
  DoWorkPrivate(int i) { isDoWorkPrivatecall = true;}
  bool isDoWorkPrivatecall = false;
}


TEST(FooTest, Run) {
  Foo *foo = new FooMocK();    
  foo->Run();
  EXPECT_TRUE(foo->isDoWorkPrivateCalled());
}
```

And YES, that means the private methods has to be protected.

At least I suggest to use [gmock](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md). The mocking-framework extends gtest with the mock features. With gmock you could mock a method

```
MOCK_METHOD1(DoWorkPrivate, void(int i));
```

Then in your specific case, the test would look like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, DoWorkPrivate(1)).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(foo, DoWorkPrivate(2)).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(foo, DoWorkPrivate(3)).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(foo, DoWorkPrivate(4)).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(foo, DoWorkPrivate(5)).Times(1);
```

Comment: my modification to the code at the end is the real answer to the question ;)

Comment: Yeah ok. I thought, my original answer was easy to transfer to his specific question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> How to check that DoWork() and DoWorkPrivate() are invoked 5 times with certain parameters (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

I can think of the following:

1. Introduce a side effect. Let them increment the value of global variable, or let them write something to a file. You can measure how many times they were called by tracking the side effects.
2. Let them increment the value of a variable you pass into the functions. You can measure how many times they were called by tracking the changes to the variables you pass to them.

**PS** There maybe other mechanisms that I am not aware of.